# Install app directly without opening app store

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store, itunes-store

This [PDF Editor](https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/pdf-editor-fill-sign-files/id1550574425) app have an option of More Apps in Settings screen which shows a list of apps.

**All apps in this list belong to same deveoper.**

Apps can be directly downloaded from there without opening the App Store.

Can anyone please guide me how to show and manage download the other apps of my account directly.

I have added screenshots for reference

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible when using SKStoreProductViewController, A view controller that provides an in-app page where the user can purchase media from the App Store. See this article:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It shows only one product but I want to show a list of products like in above screenshots. @arik

Comment: @AzharTahir - did you read through the documentation at that link? Including the `loadProduct(withParameters:completionBlock:)` method?

Comment: I have read documentation link given above. *loadProduct(withParameters:completionBlock:)* load product page of given productID. But rather than showing product page I wnat to start downloading product immediatly like given in above screenshots

Comment: @AzharTahir - I haven't used `SKStoreProductViewController`, but everything I'm reading about it shows it can do what you're asking. Have you tried it yet?